# Why is the laser in a laser cutter only visible at certain angles?

Tags: optics, laser

I recently used my school's laser cutter for the first time. During the cut, I could see light from the laser on the papers surface as it cut it when I stood a few feet away from it, but as I shifted my view to look at it almost directly overhead, the laser suddenly disappeared and I couldn't see anything at all. Why does this happen?